# Использую Tomcat 8 и соединяюсь с db mysql. Получаю java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlet, tomcat

Начал разбираться с сервлетами и jsp. Пришло время коннектиться к базе, но возникла проблема. Прошу помощи.

1. Закинул в папку Tomcat/lib **mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar**
2. В проекте создал директорию webapp/META-INF, в ней создал **context.xml**, который содержит:

   ```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <Context>
    <Resource
         name="jdbc/library"
         auth="Container"
         description="DB Connection"
         username="root"
         password="root"
         driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library"
         maxActive="10"
         maxIdle="3"
         maxWait="100"
         factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"></Resource>
    </Context>
   ```
3. Добавил в web.xml следующее:

   ```
   <resource-ref>
     <description>DB Connection</description>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/library</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>
   ```
4. Для проверки коннекта использую этот код:

   ```
      public void check() {
       try {
           InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
           DataSource dataSource =    (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/library");
           Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
           ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM book");
           System.out.println(resultSet.next());
       } catch (NamingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
   ```

Итог: получаю **java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'**

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Может быть причина в том, что _Tomcat configuration files are formatted as schemaless XML; elements and attributes are case-sensitive_? Попробуйте тег `<Resource>` написать с заглавной.

Comment: @Mihusle Прочтите книгу [Java JDBC Tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/02/jdbc-tutorial.html) называется. Там все по полочкам разложено и понятно.